# ngGridEventStartCellEdit does not trigger

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am unable to get this event fired in `angularjs` application. I am using `ng-grid`.

Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WM7Wq9suB1OdMQ4Qc8ix?p=preview)

Please let me know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the ngGrid source code https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/build/ng-grid.js
The event is broadcast, so is available to child scopes. The app controller is a parent scope and so does not hear the event. Had it been emitted then your code would work.
The difference between $emit and $broadcast is here:http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Comment: So the solution would be to either listen to
ngGridEventEndCellEdit or update the ng-grid source and add $scope.$emit('ngGridEventStartCellEdit'); to the ngCellHasFocus directive?

Comment: Having played around a bit with the source code the ngGridDirectives.directive('ngCellHasFocus' has the important code in it with $scope.isFocused being crucial to whether the cell is editable or not. If you emit ngGridEventStartCellEdit' it can certainly be 'heard'in the scope. The domUtilityService seems to be important but I haven't got time at the moment to look deeply